# Javascript function difficulty

Tags: javascript, function, input

I am new to Javascript and am having some difficulty.  I want to have the user type in a word and have a function identify the word and print it back to the user on the same page.  Everytime I run this code though it takes me to a DIFFERENT page AND prints '[object]'.  Here is my code.  Can someone please help me.

Live Long and Prosper.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function animate() {
var txt = document.getElementById("words");
document.write(txt);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

Text: <input type="text" id="words" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Animate" onclick="animate()" />

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a div to your page

`<div id='msg'></div>`

and change your js function to

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function animate() {
    var txt = document.getElementById("words").value;
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = txt;
    return false;
    }
    </script>
```

Also make the following change to your submit button

```
<input type="submit" value="Animate" onclick="return animate()" />
```

Comment: haha patience clyde.  I have one last question and you will recieve your accepted answer.  --What is the purpose of 'return false;'?       Thanks, Spock

Comment: @user1460876 : That was just a suggestion :P

Comment: `return false` when used with the submit button prevents your form from submitting. I used it coz i thought you have a form. Not relevant in your case.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
var txt = document.getElementById("words");
```

gives you an `input`, i.e. DOM object (which is represented by `[object]` when turned to string). And you want to retrieve its content, i.e. value. Try this:

```
var txt = document.getElementById("words").value;
```

Refreshing is caused by the submit button. Change its type to `type="button"`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
    function animate() {
       var txt = document.getElementById("words");
       document.write(txt);
   }
```

try with

```
   function animate() {
       var txt = document.getElementById("words").value;
       document.write(txt);
   }
```